# JQuery hasClass - why does it always return false in this case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a span with a background image that I want to alternate between a background image of a plus and minus on click. I want to add and remove the class 'open' to do this. My span looks like this...

```
<span class="expand open"></span>
```

And my JQuery looks like this...

```
$(function() {
    $('.expand').click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
            $(this).removeClass('open');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('open');
        }
    });
});
```

The behaviour I'm getting is that it will add the class 'open' but then after repeated clicks will not remove it again. Logging to the console has shown that my if statement is always evaluating false.

I've considered using toggleClass but haven't done so because once this is working I intend to use the same if statement to show / hide content blocks.

http://jsfiddle.net/Vz7YL/

EDIT
Since people are focussing on my css, I'll provide that too. (SASS/SCSS):

```
.expand {
    background: url(/images/plus-minus-orange.gif) top center no-repeat;
    display: block;
    height: 21px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 22px;
    &.open {
        background: url(/images/plus-minus-orange.gif) bottom center no-repeat;
    }
}
```

Can I also add that the span IS displaying correctly and IS clickable, and I cannot recreate the problem with a simplified version of the code.

Comment: Can you share the fiddle.

Comment: try logging $(this) so see if you're looking at the correct element.  Otherwise, your logic looks fine.

Comment: It worked for me, anyway how are you clicking on span, like this it won't show up at all. add some text in `span`.

Comment: Logging $(this) returns the following: `[span.expand, context: span.expand, jquery: "1.11.1", constructor: function, selector: "", toArray: function…]
0: span.expand.open
context: span.expand.open
length: 1
__proto__: Object[0]`

Comment: Are there any other elements with the `expand` or `open` classes? Could you create a minimal working example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: what @Mritunjay say is correct, span without any text in there is nothing, add some text on it, and it will work fine

Comment: The code given doesn't reproduce the problem. Voting to close.

Comment: the code works just fine as long as the span is actually clickable -_-

Comment: @Doorknob - I think your suggestion about a class conflict is spot on, and that wasn't something I'd thought of. Based on your comment I tried to recreate the issue using a simplified version of my code and it worked fine. If you put your response in an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Mritunjay - I did mention in my question that the plus / minus was displayed using a background image, hence the span whilst empty displays as desired due to css styling.

Comment: Because the tag span display inline, so maybe you not click exactly that span. I change your span to block, and your code work right. Please see the update fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Vz7YL/1/

Comment: @Marc - I was checking your jsfiddle, it seems to be impossible to click on span you're trying to handle click event, because it is not visible (it doesn't have any content or it doesn't have any height width). I agree with Quentin, I am also voting to close.

Comment: Btw: consider toggleClass()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While none of the answers here provide me with a solution, one of the comments on my question did. Substituting the class 'open' for and alternative such as 'expanded' resolved the problem. Thanks @Doorknob

Answer (score 1):

Your fiddle works fine for me. Just add some text in `span` So you can actually click on `span`.

```
<span class="expand open">Some Text Here</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fiddile Works fine. You need to add some text in span.

[image]

Comment: See my edit. I've now provided my css too. The problem has never been that my span will not display, or that it was not clickable, as shown by the fact that I posted the result of a console.log() earlier.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .expand {
            background: url('/Images/Icons/greenplus.png') top center no-repeat;
            display: block;
            height: 21px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 22px;
        }
        .open {
            background: url('/Images/Icons/redminus.png') bottom center no-repeat;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $('.expand').click(function () {
                if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
                    $(this).removeClass('open');
                } else {
                    $(this).addClass('open');
                }
            });
        });        
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <span class="expand open"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle works fine. So the issue is the click don't work for the background image. Try to add some width and height for the span element and try.

Like this

```
.expand {
background: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/Plus_orange.gif) top center no-repeat;
display: block;
height: 21px;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 22px;
```

}
.open {
        background: url(http://www.ilsc.com/course-resource/images/sign-minus-orange.gif) bottom center no-repeat;
    }
}

http://jsfiddle.net/Vz7YL/4/